# Intersection of conic and line

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Say I take the line $l := \{x=0\}$ in $\mathbb P^2$. If $P$ defines a conic $C:=V(P)$ it will intersect $l$ in two points. How would I write down the equation for $C$ if I want those points to be $0$ and $\infty$? Any polynomial of degree 2 will have its solutions on an affine chart.

Comment: $P=xL=yz$, where $L$ is any linear form, assuming that $y=0$ defines 0 on $x=0$ and $z=0$ defines $\infty$. These are not well defined apriori.

Comment: You can try $x^2-yz$, which is the equation for the 2-uple embedding of $\mathbb{P}^1$ into $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working in the affine chart $\{z=1\}$, we are searching for an quadratic equation, which meets the $y$-axis in the affine $xy$-plane exactly once at the origin (transversally). If we have found such an equation, we are done, since Bezout tells you, that there is another intersection point in the projective plane, which will be contained in the complement of our affine chart - i.e. in $\{z=0\}$ - and since we also have $x=0$, the second intersection point will be $[0:1:0]$.

The solutions to this easy affine problem are $y=ax^2+bx$. After homogenization, we obtain the conic $yz=ax^2+bxz$ and you if you dont trust my reasoning, you can easily verify by hand, that the intersection points with $\{x=0\}$ are $[0:0:1]$ and $[0:1:0]$.

---

If you want the conic to be irreducible, you have to make sure $a \neq 0$, i.e. kick out the solution given by the union of two lines: $yz=0$.